# Eclipse C++ include error: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt

I've loaded a C++ project into Eclipse (Europa) and I'm familiarizing myself with the CDT interface.

There is one particularly annoying error message for the following line:

```
#include "somedir/somefile.h"
```

**somedir/somefile.h: No such file or directory**

The include file exists in "/opt/local/project/include/somedir/somefile.h".

Under **Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes**, I've already added the include directory "/opt/local/project/include".

However, this does not seem to solve the issue.

Does anyone know how to deal with this error?
Thanks.

Edit:
Solved the problem. Turns out that it was a simple issue. I had to "refresh" all the projects in the workspace.

Comment: This solution worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/14614594/1729501

Answer (score 13):

Why such an old version?  Newer versions of the Eclipse CDT have made vast improvements.

This is a really obvious question, but under Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes (at least in the current CDT), there are separate categories for each language (assembly, C, and C++).  Did you make sure to add /opt/local/project/include under both C and C++ (if appropriate)?

Alternatively, if your project is built using Make, then simply building your project from within Eclipse will often let Eclipse auto-detect include directories using Make's output, without your having to set the include paths yourself.

If the paths are all set up correctly, then the standard fix for indexing-related problems is to right-click on your project, choose Index, and choose Rebuild.

Comment: Check, too, if you are actually building a single Makefile project.
My error caused the same message but was very dumb: I imported an Eclipse project located in the parent directory of multiple Makefile projects and all got messed up. As [Josh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/25507/josh-kelley) said, Eclipse could had autodetected a wrong set of include directories.

Comment: having same problem


make all 
Building file: ../swap.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"swap.d" -MT"swap.d" -o "swap.o" "../swap.cpp"
In file included from ../swap.cpp:5:0:
../boost/process/process.hpp:12:36: fatal error: boost/process/config.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'swap.o' failed
make: *** [swap.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****

in my cpp

#include "boost/process/process.hpp"


--

I have the boost folder in the project root

Comment: @user482963 - Make sure that a command line build works, if you haven't already. Unfortunately, it's probably going to be hard to diagnose an issue like this through comments; you can try a new question, if you can put together an MCVE (Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example), or you might try chat.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on project -> Index -> Freshen All Files.