# How do you add libraries to Eclipse CDT? (No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm having some issues adding header libraries.

I right click on my project, and click **Properties-> C/C++ General-> Paths and Symbols**.

In the **Includes** tab: **Languages-> GNU C++**

I click on **Add... -> File system** then add the folder called boost_1_52_0, or any other folder.

When I use Eclipse's intellisense, it finds the  that I desire, however it fails on building.

```
fatal error: boost/random/...: No such file or directory
```

Not sure why this is happening.

Any help just getting off the ground would be appreciated.

```
22:34:02 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project TestProj****
make all 
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0    -c -o TestProj.o TestProj.cpp
TestProj.cpp:5:52: fatal error: boost/random/random_number_generator.hpp: No such file     or directory
<builtin>: recipe for target `TestProj.o' failed
compilation terminated.
make: *** [TestProj.o] Error 1
```

Apparently it isn't as easy as adding a folder to the directory to the interfaces eclipse provides. I am in awe.

Regards,
Dane

Comment: Depends on project type and build policies setup (see my comment on your answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I right click on my project, and click Properties-> C/C++ General-> Paths and Symbols.
>
> In the Includes tab: **Languages-> GNU C++**
>
> I click on **Add... -> File system** then add the folder called boost_1_52_0, or any other folder.
>
> When I use Eclipse's intellisense, it finds the that I desire, however it fails on building.

Yes, that's what you might need to keep Eclipse CDT intellisense and the indexer in sync with your external references.

```
fatal error: boost/random/...: No such file or directory
```

> Not sure why this is happening.

This is because your settings for how to build the project might choose you're going to manage the build process yourself:
[image: CDT C/C++ Build Properties]

If so, you have to let know your manually managed `makefile` know about the environment and compiler/linker flag settings.

A way to communicate with the manually managed makefile with the Eclipse CDT build properties for such cases, is to use e.g. **Build Variables** or **Environment** settings from the mentioned project property section:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

What to add depends on what you are trying to include. In the case of Boost, there are a number of header-only libraries, and there are some libraries that require linking in static/shared-object libraries (e.g., serialization).

### Header-Only Libraries

For header-only libraries, you just need to include the base directory of all the header files. With `gcc`, you add the directory using the `-I` flag (e.g., `-I C:/path/to/boost_52_0`). With a managed makefile project in Eclipse, you can accomplish the same using `Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Directories`

### Static/Shared-Object Libraries

For static/shared-object libraries, you have to specify two options:

1. `-l` --> The name of the library, less the 'lib' prefix and the file suffix (e.g., `libboost_serialization.dll` -> `boost_serialization`
2. `-L` --> The directory to look for the library file in. This is only needed if the library is on a non-standard path.

As @Chris pointed out, for a managed makefile project, both of these options can be set through `Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC C++ Linker > Libraries`

Answer (score 1):

Is `Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool settings > ... Linker > Libraries` what do you search? It's where you add the -l options when compiling from command line.

Comment: I've added -I'directory' to the CXXFLAGS part of the make file. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Changing settings in `C/C++ Build` --> `Settings` solved the problem. Ensure that the ".lib" filename extension is excluded! See the screenshot below: [image]

Answer (score -4):

Solved by adding -I to makefile.

```
BOOST =     C:/Users/neo/Documents/boost_1_52

CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -I$(BOOST)

OBJS =      p1.o

LIBS =      

TARGET =    p1.exe


$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: -1 This by no way answers the question from your title, since what `makefile` is completely depends on your CDT project type. If it's a makefile project, yes. For CDT automated C/C++ projects, no!

Comment: BTW: Added `-I <what??>` to which `makefile`, an absolute path for your build enironment?

Comment: I've researched a bit on SO's bounty policies, and it's stated there that you'll never get reputation points refunded by answering the question yourself. And BTW your answer still doesn't cover what you've been questioning. It just works for you, with your particular eclipse project setup, but won't help any other user looking for an answer to _'How to add libraries to Eclipse CDT?'_ ...