# Eclipse: Add external lib for c project Not working

Tags: c, eclipse, library-path

I have done the following:

1. Create new c project (Makefile Project with Existing Code)
2. Added a build variable that my Makefile complained about
3. Now my source .c file complains about #include files because it does not know where the lib folder is,I tried adding lib folder to library path (DID NOT WORK).

How can I link my project to an external lib folder so that my .c source file can read the .h files needed for the #include?

I added the library path to Paths and Symbols->Includes BUT when I go back to the project it only shows the root folder and nothing inside it. Do I also have to add each individual .so lib file?

Comment: you added the right lib path? Maybe you also need to add something like "additional include paths"? have you additonal to the path told the linker which lib(s) to link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add libraries to Eclipse CDT? (No such file or directory)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287817/how-do-you-add-libraries-to-eclipse-cdt-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: How do you tell the linker which libs to link to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I figured it out:

(1) At the start I had a source.c and a MAKEFILE
(2) Create new c project (Makefile Project with Existing Code)
(3) MAKEFILE complained about a variable so I added it to environment variable
(4) #include files complained so I added external library like so
    (a) I located my library path and found that there is a folder before /lib called include
    (b) The include folder had a list of header files
    (c) So I added the path to the include folder NOT the lib folder  under paths and symbols     include

WORKED LIKE A CHARM!

Answer (score 1):

Answered here : [How do you add libraries to Eclipse CDT? (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287817/how-do-you-add-libraries-to-eclipse-cdt-no-such-file-or-directory)

@cyfur01 has the best answer :

> What to add depends on what you are trying to include. In the case of
>   Boost, there are a number of header-only libraries, and there are some
>   libraries that require linking in static/shared-object libraries
>   (e.g., serialization). Header-Only Libraries
>
> For header-only libraries, you just need to include the base directory
>   of all the header files. With gcc, you add the directory using the -I
>   flag (e.g., -I C:/path/to/boost_52_0). With a managed makefile project
>   in Eclipse, you can accomplish the same using Properties > C/C++ Build
>
> > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Directories Static/Shared-Object Libraries
>
> For static/shared-object libraries, you have to specify two options:
>
> ```
> -l --> The name of the library, less the 'lib' prefix and the file suffix (e.g., libboost_serialization.dll -> boost_serialization
> -L --> The directory to look for the library file in. This is only needed if the library is on a non-standard path.
> ```
>
> As @Chris pointed out, for a managed makefile project, both of these
>   options can be set through Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool
>   Settings > GCC C++ Linker > Libraries